# AWS CodeBuild Skipping invalid artifact path - not a valid identifier

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-codebuild

I have an AWS CodeBuild that processes two projects, during the build process the source will get built and bundled in zip files and placed in `bundles/*`.

The following is how the directory tree looks like, where bundles contains the generated zip files to be deployed:

[image: Directory tree]

It uses the following `buildspec.yml`:

```
version: 0.2

phases:
  install:
    commands:
      - ./manager.sh install
  build:
    commands:
      - ./manager.sh build
      - ./manager.sh package
      - ./manager.sh test
      - ./manager.sh test:functional
      - ./manager.sh test:deploy
  post_build:
    commands:
      - ls -l bundles # I see the artifacts on the console using this

artifacts:
  files: 
    - 'bundles/*'
```

After the tests, after the building passes the deploy fails. [image: CodeBuild]

This returns `Skipping invalid artifact path [edited] not a valid identifier .` (where it should be bundles)

I have tried multiple combinations of the following:

this one returns `Skipping invalid artifact path [edited] not a valid identifier bundles`

```
artifacts:
  base-directory: bundles
  files: 
    - '**/*'
```

Or this one `Skipping invalid artifact path [edited] not a valid identifier .`

```
artifacts:
  files: 
    - bundles
```

here is the full error:

```
[Container] 2018/02/12 19:13:05 Expanding /codebuild/output/tmp/env.sh: line 69: export: `npm_config_unsafe-perm': not a valid identifier
.
[Container] 2018/02/12 19:13:05 Skipping invalid artifact path /codebuild/output/tmp/env.sh: line 69: export: `npm_config_unsafe-perm': not a valid identifier
.
[Container] 2018/02/12 19:13:05 Phase complete: UPLOAD_ARTIFACTS Success: false
[Container] 2018/02/12 19:13:05 Phase context status code: CLIENT_ERROR Message: No matching base directory path found for /codebuild/output/tmp/env.sh: line 69: export: `npm_config_unsafe-perm': not a valid identifier
.
[Container] 2018/02/12 19:13:07 Runtime error (*errors.errorString: No matching base directory path found for /codebuild/output/tmp/env.sh: line 69: export: `npm_config_unsafe-perm': not a valid identifier
.)
```

Could it be my `docker container`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried multiple things, they all kept failing, so the only lead I had was this:

```
line 69: export: `npm_config_unsafe-perm'
```

Which appeared multiple times. That lines comes from my docker image. So I figured that **maybe** aws codebuild was doing a false positive for some reason on that error.

I changed my image from `lambci/lambda:build-nodejs6.10` ***to*** `roelofr/node-zip:latest` to do a quick test, and lo and behold it worked with no issues.

[image: Successful Build]

**SO YES, A DOCKER IMAGE MAY BREAK YOUR BUILD EVEN IF THE REST IS GOOD, BEWARE**

So I will change the image to something like a personal image that uses `node 6.10.3` just for validation purposes.